# How to merge two pdf in single pdf

Tags: php, pdf

I have two different pdf files, named `diff-1.pdf` and `diff-2.pdf` and a single pdf named `common.pdf`.

Now I want to merge the contents of `common.pdf` to `diff-1.pdf` and generate a new file named `first.pdf`.

After that I want to merge the contents of `common.pdf` to `diff-2.pdf` and generate a new file named `second.pdf`.

I am using the pdfmerger library. I have used following code:

```
  <?pdf
       include 'PDFMerger.php';
       $pdf = new PDFMerger;

       <!-- Merge 'common.pdf' and 'diff-1.pdf' -->
       $pdf->addPDF('commonpdf/common.pdf', 'all');
       $pdf->addPDF('allpdf/diff-1.pdf', 'all');
       $pdf->merge('file', 'pdftest/first.pdf');

       <!-- Merge 'common.pdf' and 'diff-2.pdf' -->
       $pdf->addPDF('commonpdf/common.pdf', 'all');
       $pdf->addPDF('allpdf/diff-2.pdf', 'all');
       $pdf->merge('file', 'pdftest/second.pdf');
   ?>
```

but problem is arising that this code is generating only `first.pdf` at once. But I want to generate two pdf files in a single execution of this code. What should I do for this purpose?

Comment: Could you add the docs link to PDFMerger into your question, so people can check the docs if they wish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initate a 2nd instance of [PDFMerger](http://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/) after the first merger() call.

Anyhow, you should avoid using the PDFMerger class at all, because it uses a 5 (!!) years old version of FPDI!
Just check [this demo](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/concatenate-fake/) for a simple example showing you how to concatenate documents with FPDI.

Comment: you beauty. Perfect answer for me.